# What kind of stream GStreamer produce?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer, vlc, avconv

I use following 2 commands to stream video from Raspberry Pi

**RaPi**

```
raspivid -t 999999 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=$RA-IP-ADDR port=5000
```

**Linux Box**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=$RA-IP-ADDR port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

But what kind of stream is it? Can I read it with OpenCV? or convert with `avconv|ffmpeg` `nc $RA-IP-ADDR 5000 | avconv`? or watch with VLC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stream appears to be an [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) stream encapsulated in a [GDP](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gstreamer-libs-0.10/gstreamer-libs-gstdataprotocol.html) stream, the latter of which which appears to be proprietary to GStreamer. You might be able to remove the gdppay and gdpdepay elements from your pipeline and use other RTP tools (there are plenty out there; I believe VLC supports RTP directly), but you could also use a GStreamer pipeline to pipe the depayloaded GDP stream (in this case, the H.264 stream it contains) from the RPi to a file on the Linux Box side, like so:

`gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=$RA-IP-ADDR port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! filesink location=$FILENAME`

or, to pipe it to stdout:

`gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=$RA-IP-ADDR port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! fdsink`

One or the other of these should let you operate on the H.264 video at a stream level.

GStreamer 1.0 can also interact with libav more or less directly if you have the right plugin. Use `gst-inspect-1.0 libav` to see the elements supported. The `avdec_h264` element already in your pipeline is one of these libav elements.